# QGIS spatial analysis grid nearest neighbour ERROR 4 No such file or directory Process returned error code 1

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, nearest-neighbor, spatial-analysis

Whenever I try to run some form of spatial analysis by `raster>>analysis>>Grid (Nearest Neighbour) or Grid (Inverse Distance to a Power)` I am hit with the errors and message logs below. I am trying to test it on a very small dataset that I created randomly which has an id,x and y coordinates and temperature values. How do I debug this problem?

```
QGIS version: 3.21.0-Master
QGIS code revision: 1906e19899
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.8.7
GDAL version: 3.2.3
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
PDAL version: 2.2.0 (git-version: Release)
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Grid (Nearest neighbor)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ANGLE' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'delimitedtext://file:///Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/dystopia-data/ishan/randomtempdata.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'RADIUS_1' : 0, 'RADIUS_2' : 0, 'Z_FIELD' : 'ID' }

GDAL command:
gdal_grid -l None -zfield ID -a nearest:radius1=0.0:radius2=0.0:angle=0.0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff "file:///Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/dystopia-data/ishan/randomtempdata.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no" /private/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/processing_WjqcAP/49cdcc0f2243463fbffdc7d7a5cee7f5/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: file:///Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/dystopia-data/ishan/randomtempdata.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no: No such file or directory
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.21 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/private/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/processing_WjqcAP/49cdcc0f2243463fbffdc7d7a5cee7f5/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /private/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/processing_WjqcAP/49cdcc0f2243463fbffdc7d7a5cee7f5/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
QGIS version: 3.21.0-Master
QGIS code revision: 1906e19899
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.8.7
GDAL version: 3.2.3
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
PDAL version: 2.2.0 (git-version: Release)
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Grid (Nearest neighbor)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ANGLE' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'delimitedtext://file:///Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/dystopia-data/ishan/randomtempdata.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'RADIUS_1' : 0, 'RADIUS_2' : 0, 'Z_FIELD' : 'T' }

GDAL command:
gdal_grid -l None -zfield T -a nearest:radius1=0.0:radius2=0.0:angle=0.0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff "file:///Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/dystopia-data/ishan/randomtempdata.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no" /private/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/processing_WjqcAP/bd49e38b377245c093ba37fe4db1dce1/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: file:///Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/dystopia-data/ishan/randomtempdata.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no: No such file or directory
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.19 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/private/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/processing_WjqcAP/bd49e38b377245c093ba37fe4db1dce1/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /private/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/processing_WjqcAP/bd49e38b377245c093ba37fe4db1dce1/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

`randomtempdata.csv:`

```
ID,X,Y,T
1,0.173,0.458,45.0
2,0.520,0.489,30.3
3,0.156,0.586,42.9
4,0.092,0.452,41.1
5,0.321,0.462,42.0
6,0.174,0.336,43.1
7,0.007,0.308,40.5
8,-0.142,0.748,36.2
9,0.405,0.825,32.3
10,0.488,0.647,33
11,0.629,0.149,23
12,-0.139,0.149,29
13,0.423,0.473,35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> No such file or directory

indicates that there is something wrong with your input.

Just tested a little and it seems like these tools do not like CSV-Input-Data. I suggest to convert your data to another format like GeoPackage, then it should run fine.

The issue already has been reported:

- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31267
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38485

Comment: OMG youre a life saver!!